# Symfony/Doctrine: fetching data as object , still get array

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I have in my controller $id it's a foreign key

```
  $query = $em->getRepository('SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients')->findPatientByUserID($id);
```

And in my repository file this function

```
 public function findPatientByUserID($id)
{

    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT p FROM SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients p WHERE p.user ='.$id.'')
        ->execute();

}
```

I want get an instance of object but still get an array. Query with find($id) works good

edit 
Problem solves , I'm so stupid , I had invoked to $query[0]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$query->getSingleResult();` as well

see here

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the object, you shouldn't be using DQL. Doctrine entities have a [find](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects) function that takes care of this for you.

Instead of all that code, you can just use (in your controller):

```
$em->getRepository('SurgeryPatientBundle:Patients')->find($id);
```

DQL is very powerful, but for simple lookups like this using the built in find methods will be more efficient & provide the entities as doctrine objects.

Comment: then findByUser should work if you pass a user instance i think.

Comment: It dosen't works I still get this array(1) { [0] => class Surgery\PatientBundle\Entity\Patients#914 (29) . When I find a primary key (find($id)) I get an object

Comment: `findByUser($userObject)` will return always an array. But inside your array is the Patients Object. If you need a function returning  only the Patient, just wrap it into a own function returning the first element or `null`, but be carfull nobody ensures that your User has only one Patient. If a user can have more than one Patient it makes no sense to return one Object by querying a one to many relation.